# Weird: printf() affects variable value

Tags: c, linux

Here is a block of code:

```
int somefunc() {
    /* ... */
    while ((pos = KMP_index(array, size, pattern, plen)) > -1) {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

`somefunc()` is called in multiple child processes, one call per fork.

My code compiles and works as expected on Linux x86_64 and i386. But when I run it on Atom netbook (Arch Linux i686), `count` variable never exceeds 2!

```
while (...) {
    count++;  //succesfully increments 
}
return count; //it's maximum 2!
```

However, if I add printf() :

```
while (...) {
    count++;  //succesfully increments
    printf("%d", anything);
}
return count; //value as expected
```

Printing empty character or `fflush`ing the stdout don't work here. I have to print at least one character, only then the variable is fine. And it drives me nuts.

Can someone please tell me, why would I even have to use such "workaround"?
Could it be an issue with my linux environment? (Nothing special, GCC 4.8, stock kernel)
Thank you.

P.S the whole source is here http://pastebin.com/4eEHMbKn .
Yes, it's a homework :) I need to create a grep-like utility processing every file in separate process.

Comment: Smells like undefined behaviour. Can't tell where from the visible code.

Comment: Likely that some part of your code is affecting the funct's operation and the printf changes the execution timing and so affects the outcome. Does it work unthreaded? What non-local vars are you accessing in the funct? What is the effect of one thread changing some such var upon any other thread?

Comment: You might need to tag it as `volatile` to avoid compiler optimization shortcuts.  In general it's not a good idea to mess with a variable in multiple threads or processes.  I'm not sure the behavior is defined at all if you don't explicitly control simultaneous access from multiple threads.

Comment: @ArtSwri, It does work unthreaded. The only non-local vars are the arguments: `int badgrep(const char *file, int size, const char *pattern, int plen)`.
The var in question is created and returned within the function, so it's completely local (I think?). Should I still tag it volatile, @JimStewart?

Comment: If you are using threads, or separate processes but shared memory, you could use atomic built-ins: `__sync_fetch_and_add(&counter, 1)` to increment the counter, and `__sync_fetch_and_add(&counter, 0)` to read it. However, Mike Roll, I don't think that's it. The non-empty `printf()` takes real-world time to run, so most likely you have a race condition in the `KMP_index()` function that causes the loop to only execute twice on atoms. You can verify this by adding `sched_yield()` or `usleep(1)` calls within the body (instead of the `printf()` to alter the timing): you should get the same effect.

Comment: `struct stat *st = (struct stat *)malloc(sizeof(struct stat));` complete idiot, IMnsvHO. (the stack is your friend!)

Comment: @NominalAnimal, I tried adding up to 1 second of usleep() - still, printf succeeds, usleep does not :(

Comment: @wildplasser, could you explain what's so bad about it? even if I free() it soon after?

Comment: It is not *needed* to use dynamic alloc. Using `struct stat st; stat (path, &st);` is perfectly fine, and relieves you from the obligation to `free()` the damn thing (remember: you already have an identifier there. Now you also have the obligation to free() it)

Comment: This wasn't the issue, but thanks anyway.

Comment: It was not the issue, I agree. I just got triggered on the first *stylistic* "error". IMHO the code could be reduced to 50% of the LOC (and probably 25% of the error rate) if you would avoid this kind of idiom. I'm sorry.

Comment: What happens if you run it in a debugger?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `KMP_index()` calls `KMP_failure()` to initialize the `failure[]` array. Unfortunately, `KMP_failure()` fails to initialize the first element of the array.

`KMP_index()` does examine the first element of `failure[]`. Because that value is unset, the results from `KMP_index()` are semi-random, depending on how previous function calls used stack (local variables). This explains why the result from that function depends on what you happen to call prior to the `KMP_index()` call.

(I did notice that your code compiles without any warnings on GCC 4.6.3, so the compiler did not notice that either.)

Most likely your successful tests are on a 64-bit platform, where happenstance puts something different to the first element of that array, than on that 32-bit Atom architecture. In particular, the `printf()` changes the situation, because it uses quite a bit of stack: the next invocation of `KMP_index()` will get a `failure[]` array with the initial element left over from garbage left from calling `printf()`.

In fact, compiling with `-m32` and `-m64` and different optimization settings (`-Os`, `-O3`) produce different semi-random values in the first element in `failure[]`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: As it often happens, the problem was a little chunk of uninitialized memory spoiling all the fun. Setting it `failure[0] = 0` before calling `KMP_failure()` did the trick.
Much thanks, it was not easy to spot at all.