# What are some scenario where printf() would affect a variable in c?

Tags: c, printf

I am stuck with my program because of the stated problem. When I put a printf statement before or after assigning a computed value to an array, I get correct answer. Otherwise, it's a strange number. The number is pretty consistent though. The printf does not have to contain anything relevant to the array. I check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16289578/weird-printf-affects-variable-value), but did not get much out of it. Below is part of my code:

```
int xcorr(Imdata, Kernel, sizeIm, sizeKernel, result_im)
unsigned short** Imdata;
unsigned short** Kernel;
long sizeIm[2], sizeKernel[2];
float** result_im;
{
register float Imstd, Imavg, Kernelstd, Kernelavg, combine_avg, outtmp, area;
register int bufYsize, bufXsize;
    int i,j,r,c;
register unsigned short *ImdataPtr, *KernelPtr;
register float *result;
register float val1, val2;

// kernel average and standard deviation are constant throughout this function
area = sizeKernel[0]*sizeKernel[1];
outtmp = Kernelavg = 0;

// Using the One-pass standard variance algorithm
for(i=0;i<sizeKernel[0];i++){
    KernelPtr = Kernel[i];
       for(j=0;j<sizeKernel[1];j++){
           val1 = KernelPtr[j];
        Kernelavg += val1;
        outtmp += val1*val1;
    }
}
Kernelavg /= area;
outtmp /= area;

// now the standard deviation
Kernelstd = sqrt(outtmp - Kernelavg*Kernelavg);

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Perform Correlation
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////
  bufYsize = sizeIm[0] - sizeKernel[0] + 1;
  bufXsize = sizeIm[1] - sizeKernel[1] + 1;

for(i=0;i<bufYsize;i++){
    result = result_im[i];
    for(j=0;j<bufXsize;j++){    
        combine_avg = outtmp = Imavg = 0;

        // Using one-pass method for standard variance:
        for (r = 0; r < sizeKernel[0]; r++){
            KernelPtr = Kernel[r];
            ImdataPtr = Imdata[i+r];
            for (c = 0; c < sizeKernel[1]; c++){
                val1 = KernelPtr[c];
                val2 = ImdataPtr[j+c];
                Imavg += val2;
                outtmp += val2*val2;
                combine_avg += val1*val2;
            }
        }
        outtmp /= area;
        Imavg /= area;
        // standard deviation
        if((Imstd = outtmp - Imavg*Imavg)<=SMALL_VAR){
            result[j] = 0;
            continue;
        }
        Imstd = sqrt(outtmp - Imavg*Imavg);

        combine_avg /= area;
        result[j] = (float)combine_avg-(Imavg*Kernelavg))/(Kernelstd*Imstd);

    }
}
return 0;
}
```

The error is with result, which is allocated in main as follow:

```
result = (float**)malloc(bufYsize*sizeof(float*));
if(result == NULL){
    printf("Error allocating the output array (pair num=%d)\n",k+1);
    xit_status = 1; //exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
else{
for(i=0;i<bufYsize;i++){
    result[i]=malloc(bufXsize*sizeof(float));
       if(result[i]==NULL){ 
       printf("Error allocating the output array at row %d, pair %d\n",i,k+1);
    exit_status = 1; //exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you somewhere access that array out of bounds, or otherwise overwrite the stack.

Comment: Printf should only cause effects related to reading from data.  And writing to a file.  Maybe show some code so less speculation is needed?

Comment: Is it possible that you're trying to print the value of a variable, before assigning a value to the variable?

Comment: or not allocating memory for array [so not printing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17864952/c-program-not-printing/17864992#17864992) show your code!

Comment: code added. Thank you. I'm sure i'm not accessing the array out of bounds. Not sure about the stack

Comment: So where is the `printf` which causes weirdness?  What is the error in the result?

Comment: I realized that it does not have to be printf. I can simply tamper the variable 'result' (like add 1 then subtract 1) after this function, and I would get a correct answer...

Answer (score 1):

The only way that `printf` should be able to affect a variable is via the `%n` format specifier.

```
int x;
printf("foo%nbar\n", &x);
printf("%d\n", x);  // 3
```

If anything else is being modified, then your program must be invoking *undefined behaviour* somewhere.  I suggest starting with Valgrind (or similar) to track this down.